# WSO2 identity server shows no configuration for service provider

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am trying to configure a service provider and I am expecting to see configuration steps like Inbound Authentication Configuration but when I give a service provider name and hit register, nothing happens. All I see is an empty page just with the main pane on the left. When I click List from the left pane I can see the provider I added but when I try to edit it same thing happens.
Also same thing when I try to add an Identity Provider but instead when I click the List on the Identity Providers menu, I can click on resident ıdentity Provider and then I can see a configuration menu.
I am using WSO Identity Server  5.0.0. with service pack installed.Is there something missing with my installation?

Thanks

Comment: have you followed their documentation?

Comment: I did but I just don't see the configuration items on the management console

Comment: Their(WSO2) documentation itself well enough to configure any system. please check it once you missed anything.

Comment: Turns out I had an issue with my java version. As I fixed it I am not able to see all components. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> It is impossible to happen but if you give a detail of your environment it easy to tell what was the issue. Details are Java version,OS and etc..
>  
>   I'm also using jdk1.6.0_45 in both ubuntu 14.04 and windows-7 but this type of issue never happen.
>   If you correctly [apply the SP1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Installing+the+Service+Pack) for the WSO2 IS 5.0.0 then no issue.Please read the README.txt in WSO2-IS-5.0.0-SP01(SP1) folder and carefully follow the steps.

Comment: I fixed the issue as I said above. It was a configuration problem. Thanks